# Run bash script against 2 text files as variables

Tags: bash, aws-cli

I need to run the following command in a bash script or any script for that matter:

```
$ aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier $LIST1 --log-file-name $LIST2 --region us-west-2
```

I have a text file with all the hostnames `$LIST1` and another file with all the log files names `$LIST2`.

Basically I would like to know the best way to take each entry from `$LIST1` and download all the logs for that entry from `$LIST2`.

`$LIST1` sample:

```
host1

host2

host3
```

`$LIST2` sample:

```
error/mysql-error.log

error/mysql-error.log.0

error/mysql-error.log.1
```

Example of a regular run of the command:

```
$ aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier host1 --log-file-name error/mysql-error.log--region us-west-2
```

The problem is I have 100+ hosts and each host has about 90 logs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow makes it easy to write a question that is easy to read and formatted to easily determine what is your text and what is code. Please read through [the formatting documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), and edit your question to better fit the style of the site. You'll find that encourages others to help you by answering. If they have to take extra time to decipher what you wrote you'll drive them away.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Python, Ruby, Bash and Perl? Pick one. As is your question is too broad if you want answers for all of those languages, otherwise it sounds like you're soliciting opinions, which is also not good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `bash` solution:

```
while read -r host
do
  while read -r logfile
  do
    aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier $host --log-file-name $logfile --region us-west-2 
  done < logfiles.txt
done < hosts.txt
```